# Call to undefined method Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\StreamedResponse::status()

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Laravel version : 5.2.45
PHP version : PHP Version 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::status()
I am trying to download csv using following code but getting error

My Code :

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
    "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires"             => "0",
);

$columns = array('userId', 'action', 'value', 'ipAddress', 'createdOn');

$callback = function () use ($data, $columns) {
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($file, $columns);

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        fputcsv($file, array($item['userId'], $item['action'], $item['value'], $item['ipAddress'], $item['createdOn']));
    }

    fclose($file);
};

return FacadeResponse::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`use Response;` at top of your file and then edit this line:

```
return FacadeResponse::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

to this:

```
return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```